# Iterating inside a java stream filter

Tags: java, iterator, java-stream, predicate

```
    return Arrays.stream(partNumbers.get())
        .filter(partNumber -> Objects.nonNull(partNumber.getDescription()))
        .filter(partNumber -> partNumber.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(rateAbbr.toLowerCase()))
        .findFirst();
```

The above code would try to find a partNumber from a list of partNumbers where partNumber's description contains a 'rateAbbr'.
This code worked till 'rateAbbr' was a String but now it is changed to a list of rateAbbrs and I need to find a part number whose description contains any of the rateAbbrs. I tried it with streams and no luck yet. any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.filter(partNumber -> rateAbbr.stream().anyMatch(partNumber.getDescription().toLowerCase()::contains))`

Comment: Thanks. Just a little addition for case sensitivity -partNumbers.stream().filter(partNumber -> rateAbbrs.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).anyMatch(partNumber.getDescription().toLowerCase()::contains)).findFirst();

Answer (score 0):

just create a private boolean function that iterates over the list and checks if there is match, then call it inside filter method.